# Is it POSIX compliant for find -exec /no/such/file {} \; to exit with an error?

Tags: find, posix

I am the author of a `find` replacement which attempts to be compatible with POSIX (and with many popular extensions).  Recently I noticed a discrepancy between the behaviour of my utility and other `find` implementations, and I want to know if POSIX allows my behaviour or if I need to change it.

```
$ find . -exec /no/such/file {} \;
find: ‘/no/such/file’: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
0
$ bfs . -exec /no/such/file {} \;
bfs: error: .: -exec /no/such/file: No such file or directory.
$ echo $?
1
```

At least GNU, busybox, and FreeBSD find all have exit status 0 in this case.  My implementation propagates the `execv()` error from the `fork()`ed child to the parent, while the other implementations seem to print the error directly from the child without telling the parent.

The reason I ask this question, rather than just change the behaviour to match the others, is that it seems difficult to do when using `posix_spawn()`.  Implementations of `posix_spawn()` are allowed to propagate `execv()` errors to `errno` in the parent, and e.g. `glibc` and `musl` both do this.  It seems impossible to tell whether the error occurred before or after the `fork()`, and presumably errors from before the `fork()` (e.g. `ENOMEM`) should lead to a non-zero exit status.

I have read the [POSIX specification for `find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), but it's light on details here.  However, I've heard that there are other rules documented elsewhere that might be relevant.  For example, I've heard that if a utility prints to standard error, it must also exit with a nonzero exit code, which seems to imply that the other `find`s are not compliant.  But I'm not sure where that wording is, or if it really exists.

Comment: There is no rule about having to exit with a non-zero exit code just because something was outputted to standard error. If there was, no standard shell would ever exit interactive mode with a zero exit code (the `PS1` prompt is written to standard error).

Comment: @Kusalananda The context I saw this in was about GNU `find`'s handling of `-warn`/`-nowarn` and `POSIXLY_CORRECT`.  GNU `find` defaults to `-nowarn` if `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set, due to a concern about whether they're allowed to print the warnings and exit successfully.  I'll try to dig up a link to the discussion.

Comment: So this is specifically about what the correct behaviour is for a non-standard `find` implementation depending on the use of non-standard predicates and the values of some non-standard environment variable?

Comment: Ah, here it is: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?21039.  I'm trying to find a non-dead copy of the opengroup link.

Comment: @Kusalananda No, I'm just explaining the context where I heard that.  The question itself is about POSIX-compliant functionality.

Comment: And since `-exec {} \;` can be used as a condition, you'd at least need to make a difference between a) the command running to completion but returning a failure (part of normal processing), and b) not being able to launch the command (which you might consider a hard error). And then you get all the corner cases about programs that die of a segfault, or some joker using `-exec /path/{} \;` and whatever.

Comment: The sentence "If any invocation returns a non-zero value as exit status, the find utility shall return a non-zero exit status." is in a paragraph that begins "If the primary expression is punctuated by a <plus-sign>".  It does not apply to `-exec ... \;`

Comment: If you want to be as drop-in compatible with `find` as possible, then do what it does.  If that's not important or if you/your users strongly disagree with that -exec behaviour, then do whatever you think is best.   BTW, stderr is used for warnings and debugging messages too, not just error messages.  While there may be specific rules for find and/or other specific utilities, in general printing to stderr does NOT require exiting with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIX specification for `find` says, in its `STDERR` section,

> Otherwise, the standard error shall be used only for diagnostic messages.

(“Otherwise” follows a description of `-ok`, which isn’t relevant here.)

This needs to be understood in light of [the Utility Description Defaults](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_04), which specify that

> When this section is listed as "The standard error shall be used only for diagnostic messages.", it means that, unless otherwise stated, the diagnostic messages shall be sent to the standard error only when the exit status indicates that an error occurred and the utility is used as described by this volume of POSIX.1-2017.

So it’s not true that *all* POSIX compliant utilities are only allowed to output to standard error if they exit with a status indicating an error; but it is true for utilities with the specific mention, and that includes `find`.

Comment: Thanks for finding this wording!  I've been looking for it for a while.  I guess the remaining question is now, "should `find . -exec /no/such/file {} \;` be printing those messages at all?"

Comment: You're saying, and I think I agree that POSIX currently requires `find` to exit with a non-zero exit status if it fails to execute the utility and outputs an error message about it. I've not seen any `find` implementation that would be compliant in that regard, so it could be seen as a defect in the specification. It may be worth bringing it up to the Austin Group. The spec is also not clear to me how the utility is looked up and executed. It seems to me it should say something like "as if using execvp()...". Only the environment section hints at a `$PATH` lookup

Comment: ... I suppose `find` implementations could have some utilities builtin like `busybox` `find` is able to skip the fork+exec.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I’ll open an issue (probably not before this weekend).

Comment: May be worth asking informally on the austin-group-l mailing list first as we could very well be missing something obvious.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas indeed, will do!